# Can not create a new database by using pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, internal-server-error, pgadmin-4

I was trying to create a new database on pgadmin4 on my Ubuntu computer, but I got two errors.

The first one: "Error saving properties";

The second one: "Error retrieving the information - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR".

I have been looking for an answer and I found nothing but tutorials to create without error.
I am starting to learn SQL and need to get it working as soon as possible to carry on my course.

[image: error]

[image: details]

------------OS------------

PostgreSQL 10

pgAdmin 4

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit

Comment: This is not an answer, but I'd advise that you use the command line client `psql`. It is simpler, faster and more reliable.

Comment: Do you see any error on console or in pgadmin4.log file?

Comment: How can I do that, @n33rma?

Comment: Check https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#8

Comment: "Permission denied", @n33rma

Comment: I also tried @LaurenzAlbe, but first I got: "role myusername does not exist". Then I went to pgadmin4 and created a new role but another error appeared: "role myusername is not permitted to log in".

Comment: To allow login for a role, use `ALTER ROLE role_name LOGIN`.

Comment: Read and check about read/write permissions for the directories you use. I would also add `ALTER ROLE role_name CREATEDB` just to be sure :)

Answer (score 3):

You should clear Encoding field in Definitions tab, when you click save button it still show error popup but the database will be created.
It seem pgAdmin 4 have a bug in its psycopg2 lib. I just wrote a question for that:
[Error when create database from pgadmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022470/error-when-create-database-from-pgadmin4)

Comment: this Works. In case you miss it, to clear the encoding field, you should click on the little x near the option. :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in other answer before , this works:
**clear Encoding field in Definitions tab**

In my case the default was UTF8 , and I had to clear that to Nothing.