# Error when create database from pgadmin4

Tags: python, psycopg2, pgadmin-4

When I create database from pgadmin 4, it always show error popup: Error saving  properties.

My computer info:

- Linux Mint 18.3
- pgAdmin 4 2.1 from https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt
- Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

My error in pgadmin4.log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 180, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 168, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/views.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/browser/utils.py", line 242, in dispatch_request
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/browser/server_groups/servers/databases/__init__.py", line 157, in wrapped
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/browser/server_groups/servers/databases/__init__.py", line 489, in create
    data=data, conn=self.conn
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 128, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 110, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 989, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 754, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/browser/server_groups/servers/databases/templates/databases/sql/default/create.sql", line 10, in top-level template code
    ENCODING = {{ data.encoding|qtLiteral }}{% endif %}{% if data.datcollate %}
  File "/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 2079, in qtLiteral
    adapted.encoding = 'utf8'
AttributeError: attribute 'encoding' of 'psycopg2.extensions.QuotedString' objects is not writable
```

Comment: I think problem is in Debian installer, I installed as steps given https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu and it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting out two lines in python code resolves the issue:

```
sudo sed -i '2078,2079 s/^[^#]/#/' 
/usr/share/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/utils/driver/psycopg2/__init__.py
```

The lines are:

```
   if hasattr(adapted, 'encoding'):
       adapted.encoding = 'utf8'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need psycopg > 2.6.2. See https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/331

Comment: I tried update psycopg ('2.7.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)') and still get this very same error. I will try later following n33rma adice. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Install the python-psycopg2 complement, in ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

That Works for me !

Regards !