# Why PgAdmin 4 can't create database?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I install pgadmin 4 from apt and latest postgres 10 from Docker. And I can't create database. When I try to create it I get error "Error saving properties. Click for details"

Version2.1
CopyrightCopyright 2013 - 2018, The pgAdmin Development Team
Python Version3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
Flask Version0.10.1
Application ModeDesktop
Current Userpgadmin4@pgadmin.org

Comment: Enable debug logging in pgAdmin4 and check for any errors in pgAdmin4.log file,
Ref:https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#8
Provide error details from the log file.

Comment: I ran into the same issue and this answer helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022541/875083

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not create a new database by using pgadmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574770/can-not-create-a-new-database-by-using-pgadmin4)